# Swap positions of two SKSpriteNodes and wait for completion

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a function which should swap the position of two SKSpriteNodes (Card is a subclass) with SKAction.move:

```
func animateSwapCard(card1 :Card, card2: Card, duration:TimeInterval) {
    let inital = card1.position
    card1.run(SKAction.move(to: card2.position, duration: duration))
    card2.run(SKAction.move(to: inital, duration: duration))
}
```

Both SKActions should run simultaneously, but animateSwapCard() should return after both SKActions are completely done. I tried to create a SKAction.sequence with both actions and a SKAction.wait, but it didn't work.

The function gets called multiple times in an other function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    placeCards()
    // get refrences to cardA and cardB
    animateSwapCard(card1: cardA, card2: cardB, duration: 1)
    // get refrence to cardC
    animateSwapCard(card1: cardB, card2: cardC, duration: 1)
    // get refrences to card D and cardE
    animateSwapCard(card1: cardD, card2: cardE, duration: 1)
}
```

What happens is that the second and third call to animateSwapCard() starts immediately after the first one. It doesnt wait for the animaion to finish before going to the next. All cards start to move at the exact same time.

What i want to archive is that cardA and cardB change places. After that animations is finished, cardB and cardC change places. After that, cardD and cardE should do the same.

Comment: it doesn't work is not descriptive enough. What doesn't work? what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a few ways you can do this

The problem is that all the actions are being triggered at the same time. the code doesn't know that you want a delay between the actions, because you haven't told it to delay.

the simplest solution which should help you understand what problem is happening is the following.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    placeCards()

    var wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)

    // get refrences to cardA and cardB
    animateSwapCard(card1: cardA, card2: cardB, duration: 1)

    // get refrence to cardC
    self.run(wait) {
         animateSwapCard(card1: cardB, card2: cardC, duration: 1)
    }

    wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
    // get refrences to card D and cardE
    self.run(wait) {
        animateSwapCard(card1: cardD, card2: cardE, duration: 1)
    }
}

func animateSwapCard(card1: Card, card2: Card, duration: TimeInterval) {
    let inital = card1.position
    card1.run(SKAction.move(to: card2.position, duration: duration))
    card2.run(SKAction.move(to: inital, duration: duration))
}
```

although that method is ugly and if you wanted to do more than two swaps it becomes a pain in the butt.

You could use a completion closure on the function.

```
func animateSwapCard(card1: Card, card2: Card, duration: TimeInterval, complete: () -> ()) {
    let inital = card1.position
    card1.run(SKAction.move(to: card2.position, duration: duration))
    card2.run(SKAction.move(to: inital, duration: duration)) {
        complete()
    }
}
```

and use it like so

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    placeCards()

    // get refrences to cardA and cardB
    animateSwapCard(card1: cardA, card2: cardB, duration: 1) {

        // get refrence to cardC
        animateSwapCard(card1: cardB, card2: cardC, duration: 1) {

            // get refrences to card D and cardE
            animateSwapCard(card1: cardD, card2: cardE, duration: 1) { }
        }
    }
}
```